# Guardar/leer un struct que contiene un vector en un archivo binario

Tags: c++, array, struct

Quiero guardar el siguiente struct en un archivo binario:

```
struct Usuario{
char nombre[256];
char apellido[256];
char ingresos[256];
std::vector<Bill> manejador_facturas;
};
```

Bill también es un struct:

```
struct Bill{
float monto;
int dia;
int mes;
int anio;
char empresa[256];
};
```

Lo que traté de hacer para guardar la información en el archivo binario fue:

```
void Perfil::GuardarEnBinario(std::ostream &archivo) {
Usuario reg;
Bill auxiliar;
strcpy(reg.nombre, nombre.c_str());
strcpy(reg.apellido, apellido.c_str());
strcpy(reg.ingresos, ingresos.c_str());
for(size_t i = 0; i < manejador_facturas.size(); i++){
    strcpy(auxiliar.empresa, manejador_facturas[i].empresa);
    auxiliar.monto = manejador_facturas[i].monto;
    auxiliar.dia = manejador_facturas[i].dia;
    auxiliar.mes = manejador_facturas[i].mes;
    auxiliar.anio = manejador_facturas[i].anio;
    reg.manejador_facturas.push_back(auxiliar);
}
archivo.write((char*)&reg, sizeof(reg));
}
```

Al principio pensé que funcionaba porque el .exe funcionaba normalmente, pero el problema es que la información que ingresé no se mostraba correctamente cuando la trataba de ver (desconozco si el .bin que se generaba estaba corrupto o qué). El código para leer el struct desde el archivo binario es:

```
void Perfil::LeerDesdeBinario(std::istream &archivo) {
Usuario reg;
Bill auxiliar;
archivo.read((char*)&reg, sizeof(reg));
nombre = reg.nombre;
apellido = reg.apellido;
ingresos = reg.ingresos;
for(size_t i = 0; i < reg.manejador_facturas.size(); i++){
    strcpy(auxiliar.empresa, reg.manejador_facturas[i].empresa);
    auxiliar.monto = reg.manejador_facturas[i].monto;
    auxiliar.dia = reg.manejador_facturas[i].dia;
    auxiliar.mes = reg.manejador_facturas[i].mes;
    auxiliar.anio = reg.manejador_facturas[i].anio;
    manejador_facturas.push_back(auxiliar);
}
}
```

Algo estuve leyendo sobre el guardado de variables que no son del tipo POD, pero no pude avanzar para nada. Les agradecería un poco de ayuda porque necesito terminar este proyecto cuando antes. Muchas gracias!

Comment: En el `for` de `GuardarEnBinario`, ¿no debería ser `for(size_t i = 0; i < reg.manejador_facturas.size(); i++)`?, `manejador_facturas` propiamente creo que no existe.

Comment: `manejador_facturas` pertenece a la clase que contiene dichas funciones. Olvide aclarar eso.

Comment: Tienes un código muy raro ... ¿ Para que copias las cosas en `reg` en lugar de escribirlas directamente ? ¿ Porqué no usas la I/O de C++ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Algo estuve leyendo sobre el guardado de variables que no son del tipo POD.

No se qué leerías al respecto, pero no parece que hayas aplicado lo que has leído. Un dato de tipo [POD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/PODType) es un tipo [trivial](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TrivialType), de [disposición estándar](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType) en que todos sus miembros son también POD.

Un tipo trivial es [trivialmente copiable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable) (su copia no tendrá efectos secundarios), no es un tipo virtual, no tiene funciones virtuales ni hereda de un tipo virtual.

Un tipo tiene disposición estándar si todos sus miembros tienen el mismo tipo de acceso, no tiene funciones virtuales ni hereda de un tipo virtual, no tiene miembros de tipo referencia y todos sus miembros tienen disposición estándar.

En resumen, todas las características mencionadas en los párrafos anteriores se pueden resumir en: Un tipo POD puede ser copiado bit a bit sin que sus datos se vean afectados.

Resulta que tu tipo `Usuario` no es un tipo POD, por lo tanto no puedes copiarlo bit a bit sin afectar a su estructura interna. `Usuario` no es un POD porque uno de sus miembros no lo es: `manejador_facturas`.

#### Serializar y deserializar.

El proceso que estás llevando a cabo se conoce como [serialización](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serializaci%C3%B3n) y deserialización, la manera habitual de serializar contenedores de datos (como `std::vector`) es separar la información de dicho contenedor en tamaño y datos:

| tamaño | dato 1 | dato 2 | dato 3 | … | dato X |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | … | … | … | … | … |

De esta manera, en el momento de deserializar puedes saber de antemano cuántos datos necesitas leer del archivo. En C++ moderno la manera habitual de enfrentar este proceso es mediante la sobrecarga del operador de inyección (`<<`) en o extracción de (`>>`) flujo de datos:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Bill &b)
{
    o.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&b.monto), sizeof(b.monto));
    o.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&b.dia), sizeof(b.dia));
    o.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&b.mes), sizeof(b.mes));
    o.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&b.anio), sizeof(b.anio));
    o.write(b.empresa, 256);
    return o;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Usuario &u)
{
    o.write(u.nombre, 256);
    o.write(u.apellido, 256);
    o.write(u.ingresos, 256);

    // Guardamos tamaño.
    std::vector<Bill>::size_type facturas = u.manejador_facturas.size();
    o.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&facturas), sizeof(facturas));
    // Guardamos facturas una a una.
    for (const auto &b : u.manejador_facturas)
        o << b;

    return o;
}
```

Con el código anterior, puedes guardar un `Usuario` en un archivo binario así:

```
if (std::ofstream datos{"datos.bin", std::ofstream::bin})
{
    datos << usuario;
}
```

Para extraer datos necesitas el operador correspondiente:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &i, Bill &b)
{
    i.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&b.monto), sizeof(b.monto));
    i.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&b.dia), sizeof(b.dia));
    i.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&b.mes), sizeof(b.mes));
    i.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&b.anio), sizeof(b.anio));
    i.read(b.empresa, 256);
    return i;
}

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &i, Usuario &u)
{
    i.read(u.nombre, 256);
    i.read(u.apellido, 256);
    i.read(u.ingresos, 256);

    // Leemos tamaño.
    std::vector<Bill>::size_type facturas{};
    i.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&facturas), sizeof(facturas));
    // Leemos facturas una a una.
    for (decltype(facturas) factura = 0; factura != facturas; ++factura)
    {
        Bill b{};
        i >> b;
        u.manejador_facturas.push_back(b);
    }

    return i;
}
```

Y podrás leer un `Usuario` en un archivo binario así:

```
Usuario usuario;
if (std::ifstream datos{"datos.bin", std::ofstream::bin})
{
    datos >> usuario;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVXdbtMwFL5OnsIEaUtZl/2xAWmJBBKbkBjiAq4YqpzE2QxNHNkO04jyUDwDD1aOHTtt03ZqV1Wt7fP5/H/HSVke3ibJbPacFsm0SgkaUyYkJziP3PlZtnr0mySS8ch1QVQlEr2n02ntZlOGJcpZIdnIpYVEKcXtIieiXeCCgiy5wxyRvORE4O@n5xc/Rm4z6pR9ExXmlNUtrGB5zIlB6RNckumUpmzxjBa3oIwJcyZkGoatk2PlW4RyXJCfOGV8kuFEVhwLaxOQJmi0x0rCsbo09nuCIUpYIdpI0V48cGsXwYcF95xK4nMC0REOEclJgoUct2jt24vI34sDnZbBEAn6h7DMtweD0Y56IKeLWtR2Zx1QjiVPYLuzDlXJRSV639MSB6bIQwR1MUJQWfECQRs0u6ff9Abaq/oVqIK2UxZNzWW2Z9ZLbfdYqRYfHaErMJbinAkkcY7//WWBlqx0VxiqNEzkQ0mQbS/0FlXBatcFCunvmG17eZ7v7sRoWnK2c6EqMMLqt/U7Yxz5rWpcSUhijMK1Tg40XHuIxmMUm4ysVo72KxdF/rKADvuUoQFI0jUxb8uVLRRsJsk21jeyY4vLj9HCXH@MFXTH3K7ywRhZR4dOtI4NnXATGT4R8jQm1M2W2duqzY0bj/Z4SpKpcmF@3@KBlcejbvPsbadnhA4OzLrt/rrjgO7f2EahI0FRpFhh92uJXlbibhLj5JcfG@8bd7XU@nXEtPBV/Rxbzso8gd5V9XDPWOoNkfeVE1LGHLSq3XWV3DEBq1q/vecvz4LTk2yITqBs8D0@gV/vC4XGIfA4Jl7T8rB@8/pVcHGeadSZAp6e9YCNehYdmiEzg83zj1LoQVF7@i@IaQG223ZkIgxhj/lDM3AdiMLRGDU5TBwj12kWddIn6OxSowphTUAZKuWto28lrJKwdsCw91l3f4g87YYhg1rv3xT7FvTO8KCDWWL0gR8NJzqgJUkfeGmqH94UnnJzdeRumriOjnI5EK3yRl6r6ddaNqNw0awBXRLgkQXBwNOQw31ziYilvZpKa3R8aOeS1WLGlAWqeJq2kqaFj6GFZ7P/)</kbd>.

Comment: Tu código me ha funcionado a la perfección, muchas gracias! Sin embargo, a la hora de guardar los datos, si no hay por lo menos un `Bill` guardado, no se guardan/leen de manera correcta los usuarios, por ende, falla el programa en su totalidad. ¿Qué me recomiendas hacer? Se me ocurrió cargar por defecto siempre un `Bill` con sus valores inicializados en cero, evitando en el programa principal operar sobre el.

Comment: Si tienes fallos de ejecución, mi propuesta no funcionó a la perfección. En el código que comparto funciona correctamente así que en tu caso o el compilador no es el mismo o no hiciste lo mismo. Te recomiendo depuración paso por paso y si no avanzas tal vez podrías plantearte redactar una nueva pregunta.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>rollazo_teorico="on"</kbd>

¿ No te ha parecido raro que, por muchos `Usuario::manejador_facturas.push_back( )` que hagas, el tamaño de `struct Usuario` sea siempre el mismo ?

En otras palabras, no puedes tratar una estructura de datos dinámica como si fuera estática. El número de elementos contenido en un `std::vector< >` puede variar en el tiempo, pero el resultado de `sizeof( manejador_facturas )` **siempre va a ser el mismo**, por lo que el resultado de `sizeof( Usuario )` también lo será.

Debes realizar un trabajo adicional para guardar una estructura dinámica en un archivo: establecer una manera de indicar cuantos elementos tiene, y luego recorrer esos elementos e ir almacenándolos de 1 en 1.

Adicionalmente, **nunca jamás de los jamases** puedes asumir que en distintas ejecuciones de tu programa las posiciones de memoria usadas van a coincidir al 100%. Si en esta ejecución tienes un dato cualquier en la posición de memoria `0x100`, **no puedes asumir que al terminar el programa y volver a ejecutarlo el dato va a estar en la misma posición**.

¿ A que viene esto ? Pues a que `std::vector< >`, como estructura dinámica que es, **utiliza punteros** internamente para indicar donde están realmente guardados los datos. Si lo guardas y lo recuperas *a lo bruto*, obtendrás un acceso a memoria erróneo. Lo cual, con suerte, terminará tu programa con un error del Sistema Operativo ... o, con mala suerte, corromperá tus datos y terminarás guardando en disco basura aleatoria inutilizable, sin ninguna forma de recuperar los datos reales.

Un apunte extra: **no se te ocurra** guardar/cargar instancias de clases que tengan métodos virtuales (`virtual`), incluido el destructor. Se sale del ámbito de la pregunta, pero es aplicable lo dicho sobre punteros y posiciones de memoria.

<kbd>rollazo_teorico="off"</kbd>

Un ejemplo de como guardar correctamente un `std::vector< >`, definiendo el `operator<<` de `std::ostream` para poder hacerlo de forma natural:

```
template< typename T, typename ALLOC >
std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &os, const std::vector< T, ALLOC > &vector ) {
  os << vector.size( );

  for( const auto &item : vector ) {
    os << item;
  }

  return os;
}
```

Recuerda lo dicho en la parrafada inicial: tenemos que almacenar el número de elementos, y a continuación cada elemento individual.

Con lo anterior, y **una vez tengas definido el operador `<<`** para todos tus tipos de datos, podrías hacer las operaciones de *escritura* mucho mas legibles y naturales:

```
std::vector< int > myVector{ 10, 15, 20 };
std::cout << myVector;
```

La operación de lectura es similar:

```
template< typename T, typename ALLOC >
std::istream &operator>>( std::istream &is, std::vector< T, ALLOC > &vector ) {
  std::size_t limit;

  is >> limit;

  for( unsigned count = 0; count < limit; ++count ) {
    T tmp;
    is >> tmp;
    vector.push_back( tmp );
  }

  return is;
}
```

Al igual que en la escritura, **es necesario** definir los `operator>>` para tus tipos, de otra forma no funcionará. **Además**, es necesario definir el constructor por defecto (creamos un elemento temporal).

Observa que estamos usando tipos dependientes de la arquitectura (`size_t`), y sin tener en cuenta su *Endian*. Eso quiere decir que un archivo guardado en un PC con micro de 64 bits **no podrá ser leído** en otra máquina con arquitectura diferente.

Última observación: tampoco estamos haciendo ningún chequeo de errores ni usando *números mágicos* de ningún tipo ... si intentamos leer un archivo corrupto, o directamente un archivo que no hemos guardado nosotros, los resultados serán ... curiosos :-)

Comment: No es necesario definir el constructor por defecto, éste está definido por defecto y desaparece si se define un constructor.