# No puedo escribir un string muy largo en un archivo binario. C++

Tags: c++, binary-files

estoy tratando de escribir un string bastante largo (1658 caracteres) en un archivo binario

Cuando me enseñaron a leer y escribir archivos binarios me lo enseñaron de la siguiente forma:

```
string a="GGGGCATCCTGGGCCCAATCGCACATTCCAGGGAGGGATACCAGGGGCGTCGAGGGGCCGGCAAAGCGGAGGGAAAGCCTCTCGAGGCGGACTAGTGCCGCGCGCTGTCCGACCAAGGAACCTAAACAGTATTGGGTGAGGTGGCAAAGATCAGCAATGCAACAAGCAATGTGGGAGCGCTCGTAATGAAAACAGCAAAGCCACCCAGGGGATCGGGGCGACGTGAGCTAAACTGCATGTGTACCAGAAACTACCGCCCAGTATGTCTGATATGAACCAAACGACGACGCAACCCGCGCAAGGATGGAAAGAGGCCTGAGATCCGCACCCCGCAGGGGCACTAAAGCACCCTAACAAAGAGCACTGCAAAAATTGGCTAGCATAATACCATTTGATTAAGTAGCCCGCATTTGCACATCTGCCAGTGGACAGGCGCGCCTAGAACGCGGTCGTCACCATGAACGCGCCGACCGGCTTATGCGGACAGCGTAGCCATTGGGCGAGTAGCACGGTTCAGGGCGAATGAACAGTAGTGAAGACTGAGAAGCCCTCGAAAACTAAAAAGAACAGCGTTGAGTACTGCGAACGCGATATGAACGGATGCCAAAAACAGCAGACTCTATGGCAATATGCCAGGCGGACGAGTCTATAACTCCTGAGGCATCGAAGAGGGAACGCAAGCAACCTCTGACCGACGTTACCAAGGAGTGCCGTAGATATAGAAAACGCGGCAGGCAGGTTGGACGTTCAAGTGTCGTTGAGTAGCCGAACAGACCCGGTGCCAAGTTTAGGGGAAATAAAAATCAGCCCGCCCCGTCGCAAATTGGAGGAGAAGCGCACGCCCGGTTAACAATCGAATCGGGCCAGGGCGAGACACCCGAGGTCACCCGCAAACATAACACCTTTCATCAGAAGAGCGTCGCGAAGCCCGTGCGATGGGCCGACACAGTGCTATATCCATTGCTGTGGAGGTCTCAGATGAAAAGCAAGGACGTCGCAGCGCGGATCTACAAAAGGCATACCCCAGATATTTACAGTAGAGAGAGTCACATCAGCCCAGCGGCGACCGTGCAGATGTGTACCGCGCCACCGGTGTAAATGCTCGCACAACAACGGGCACGCCGTAAGGAGGAGTGTACTAGTACAATTACAGGCATCCGGGCAAATGAGCAGAAAACCACAGGCCAAGGAGAAACGGATGGGAATTCAGAGAACAATTTGAGGGAAGCTGTCGCCGGACGCCGGGTCAACCTGTACCATCAATGCGGGGGGGGGCGTTTCTAAAAGACGAAAAAGAGCCGCTGATCTTGAAGCGCACGACCGGTCGGCCTCTAGGAAAACCTGTCAGACACTGCTCGGCGGCTGGAAGTCAAGAGGCGTCACGCGAAGGCAGATGCGGTAGACACGACCATGACTCGTAACGTCCAAACCCAAGGAAAGCTAGGATGAAAGCCTCGATGGGCGAAGCAGGATGGAGCGCTGCAAGGGCGAAGCAACAGAAAGCGGAGAGCGGAGTAGGCAATTCAGTGTTGCCCGCTCGCGAGAGGGCTCCCAAGACAATGCGTACACAATGGGAGGAATGACTGCTTGCTCGAGGAAAACAAAACCTCCTAAAGAGCTTAGCCTGGTAATAGGAAATGTGTGTCTGCACGAGAAA";
ofstream out("Ejemplo.dat", ios::binary | ios::out);
out.write((char*)&a,sizeof(string)); //Aquí sinceramente no se si es sizeof(string) o sizeof(a)
out.close();
```

Se supone que de esta forma se escribe y de la siguiente se lee:

```
string b
ofstream in("Ejemplo.dat", ios::binary | ios::in);
out.read((char*)&b,sizeof(string)); //Aquí sinceramente no se si es sizeof(string) o sizeof(a)
out.close();
```

No sé cuál es el error, ya que cuando trata de hacer el proceso el string b queda vacío.
Tengo otra duda, si el objeto que quiero leer tiene un arreglo dentro, al hacerlo de esta forma se escriben los elementos que están dentro de la lista?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Escritura

La forma que estás usando es correcta. Almacenas el objeto `string`. **Pero** no almacenas la cadena en sí.

Un objeto `string` es realmente algo parecido a esto:

```
struct String {
    char *data;
    size_t dataLengtn;
};
```

Internamente, usa un puntero a la cadena real. Recuerda que, en C++, todo ha de tener un tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación. Ello implica que cualquier cosa *dinámica* (`std::string`, `std::vector`, `std::map`, ...) ha de usar, como mínimo, un puntero interno para almacenar sus datos dinámicos.

Y la función `write( )` hace exactamente lo que su nombre sugiere, y podemos deducir de sus argumentos:

```
write( const char_type* s, std::streamsize count );
```

Escribe `count` *bytes*, comenzando en la dirección apuntada por `s`.

Visto el problema, la solución es sencilla: si lo que queremos escribir es *la cadena en sí*, necesitamos alguna forma de obtener tanto un puntero a ella como su tamaño. Y la clase `std::string` nos proporciona las funciones para ello: [`c_str( )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) y [`size( )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size). Por lo tanto, tu código quedaría:

```
out.write( a.c_str( ), a.size( ) );
```

#### Lectura

La lectura de un `string` es algo mas *complicadilla*. Como ya habrás supuesto, necesitamos conocer el tamaño real de los *bytes* a leer. Y tu código no almacena esa información, así que tenemos que limitarnos a leer un tamaño conocido.

Además, si queremos cumplir con el estándar, tenemos que obtener la dirección de escritura como la dirección del primer *byte* de la cadena: no debemos usar `c_str( )`.

La idea es crear una cadena del tamaño adecuado, y *machacar* su contenido, escribiendo directamente sobre los datos que gestiona:

```
string b( TAMANO_CADENA, ' ' );

ofstream in( "Ejemplo.dat", ios::binary | ios::in );
out.read( &b[0], TAMANO_CADENA );

out.close( );
```

#### Cadenas dinámicas

Si cambiamos un poco tu código original, ya podríamos tanto leer como escribir cadenas de cualquier tamaño; basta con guardar ese tamaño en el propio archivo:

Escritura:

```
string a = " ... ";
ofstream out( "Ejemplo.dat", ios::binary | ios::out );

auto size = a.size( );

out.write( reinterpret_cast< char * >( &size ), sizeof( size ) );
out.write( a.c_str( ), a.size( ) );

out.close( );
```

Lectura:

```
string b;
size_t length;

ofstream in( "Ejemplo.dat", ios::binary | ios::in );

in.read( reinterpret_cast< char * >( &length ), sizeof( length ) );

b.assign( length, ' ' );

in.read( &b[0], length );

in.close( );
```

Esta forma de escribir es *dependiente de la plataforma*: es decir, no está garantizado que puedas escribir datos en una máquina y leerlos en otra máquina distinta.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Entonces, cuando serializo un objeto, lo mejor es hacer un método dentro de él que serialice sus atributos uno a uno?

Comment: La forma común de hacerlo en C++ es definir tu propio `std::ostream::operator<<( )`. En [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/326328/19610) tienes un ejemplo y explicaciones adicionales. Y creo recordar que en el sitio hay ya varias preguntas sobre el tema ... lo difícil será encontrarlas :-/